# Importing large number of RSS feeds

Tags: rss, automation

I've developed a website in which I want to display posts from RSS feeds from other websites. I've used wordpress ofc and after lots of trial and error with RSS importers I found that Multi-Importer plugin does exactly what I need (no, autoblogged doesn't fit my needs).

My problem is that right now I'm importing feeds from 130 RSS feeds, and the server runs out of memory and website is lagging like hell. I moved the website into a new VPS with 4 cores and 8GB of RAM, and each time it checks for new RSS it takes up all the RAM and every 6 hours it crashes the mySQL server.

So simply put right now the website is very very slow, and every 4-6 hours mySQL is crashed.
How to improve the performance of this website?

Comment: It seems that this is your first question, Wellcome. The description of your question seems too board and mainly opinion based for the format of this site. If you can narrow down your question to specific parts it is possible that you get better answers.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome cybmeta, i've edited my question.
Simply put, i want to autopost from RSS feeds. from 300-500 RSS feeds. how can i improve the whole proccess?

Comment: Show us the code you are using so we can see what can be improved, if something. Note that support for third party plugins are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem solved by changing to InnoDB as storage engine for mySQL and using the following settings:

## CACHES AND LIMITS

tmp-table-size = 128M
max-heap-table-size = 128M
query-cache-type = 1
query-cache-size = 128M
max-connections = 500
thread-cache-size = 35
open-files-limit = 65535
table-definition-cache = 4096
table-open-cache = 4096

## INNODB

innodb-flush-method = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group = 2
innodb-log-file-size = 32M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table = 1
innodb_file_per_table = 1

## innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G